# how can I treat whitespace as logical AND in elasticsearch unified highlighter

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

Currently what I want to do is to treat the elasticSearch highlight query whitespace as a logical and because for example when I give it the following query

`"New Zealand" | (flutter | This part should be treated as logical and words)`

The part after the flutter is broken down as logical OR but I don't want this behavior.

I can't find anything in the docs that is helpful.

I tried using require field match but it doesn't help in this case

This is my current highlight

```
    highlight: {
      number_of_fragments: 5,
      fragment_size: 100,
      require_field_match: 'true',
      pre_tags: ['<mark style="background-color: #ffff00;">'],
      post_tags: ['</mark>'],
      fields: [
        {
          title: {
            number_of_fragments: 0,
          },
        },
        {
          description: {
            number_of_fragments: 0,
          },
        },
        {
          'attrs.prettyName': {
            number_of_fragments: 0,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
```

Comment: Do you want the continues highlight for this words `This part should be treated as logical and words`

Comment: Yeah exactly. I want it to highlight as if it was a single sentence similar to if I did `"This part should be treated as logical and words"`

Comment: No that cant possible due to existing issue in Apach Lucene and Elasticsearch. You can check [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/29561)

Comment: @SagarPatel Thank you man. This is my issue. I'll try some of the workarounds in the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned in comment, it is due to the existing highlighting open issue in Elasticsearch as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/29561).

There are some workaround mentioned in issue comments that you can try it out.